# Adding Facebook Photos to my personal website?

Tags: facebook

sorry if this has been asked before, but I was wondering how you would be able to grab individual Facebook photos (not entire albums) and put them directly onto a personal website. I am not familiar with how to use the Facebook Photo API, so if that is the correct method, would someone be able to explain how to use it?

The website's language is HTML with some CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [Embedded Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/) feature

[image: Embed a post]

For fine tuned programming, you haven't stated your website language or what is the exact issue you are having or anything like that, so you need to be more specific.

Consider reading the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/photo and then come back with a specific question about implementation.